# ASP.NET Core and Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Core with Firebase for my project.

I created an ASP.NET Core, Razor Pages project and installed the FirebaseAdmin NuGet Package in my solution. I created a C# file and put in the following code.

```
using FirebaseAdmin;

namespace web_pushNotifications
{
  public class FirebaseInitialization
   {
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = Google.Credential.GetApplicationDefault();
        });
   }
}
```

I'm getting red squiggly lines from lines 7 to 10 in my Visual Studio 2019 editor, indicating that there seem to be some context issues, but I was following the firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/) and I don't think I'm making any syntax issues. Any idea why I'm getting these errors?

My Errors:
[Image or Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVmDj.png)

Comment: What `errors` are you getting? Can you post those errors here?

Comment: My bad, I just updated my question with an image of the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the errors you need a create a method and use your firebase app object there. And your class should look like this:

```
using FirebaseAdmin;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;

public class FirebaseConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),
        });
    }
}
```